# How to list remote files from Android via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I haven't found any example on how to have a list of files present in the paired device in Bluetooth in Android app?
How can it be done?

Comment: can you found any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

you can download a app named Bluetooth File Transfer form the Android Market, it does your intended task...and provides a facility to transfer app too....